# numerical approximation to logarithm

Tags: approximation

we know that $$ \ln(x)=\frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{1}dt \frac{1}{1+xt} $$

then given a cuadrature formula inside $(0,1)$ is that true

$$ \ln(x)= \frac{1}{x}\sum_{i}\frac{w_{i}}{1+xt_{i}} $$

wht other rational approximations of logarithm are useful based on rational functions ?? $ R(x)$

Comment: We know this?  I don't.  It appears to me that the integral is incorrect.

Comment: @RonGordon, I also thought the integral was incorrect, but if we perform the change of variables $u=1+xt$, then $du=xdt$, this $x$ cancels the other one outside, and $u$ ranges from $1$ to $x$ as in the usual definition.

Comment: @user1620696: no, $dt=du/x$ and the $x$ outside does not cancel.  You end up with $\log{(1+x)}/x^2$.

Comment: @RonGordon, sorry, I didn't note that, I thought the wrong way arround. It's really incorrect.

Comment: so my expression should be $ ln(x)= x\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dt}{1+xt} $

Comment: @JoseGarcia, this new expression isn't $\ln(x)$, rather it is $\ln(x+1)$.

Comment: OK you are right perhapsh i should use this expression plus a power series involving  teh difference $ln(x+1)-ln(x) $